# Event is not supported for semi join inner selects

Tags: soql

I'm trying to get a phone number from an Account with a completed Event in SOQL.  Here is my query

```
select Phone from Account where Name in (select School_Name__c from Event where Visit_Status__c = 'Completed')
```

I get an error that says

> Entity 'Event' is not supported for semi join inner selects

Is this possible to do in one SOQL query?

Answer (score 5):

No. You can only do a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) on Id values anyway. Trying to join on Name would never work, regardless of which objects are involved. If you don't have too many `Event` records and you're in an `Apex` context, it wouldn't be an excessive amount of extra work/governor consumption to just loop through and collect the values:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
for (Event record : [
    SELECT TransAm_School_Name__c FROM Event
    WHERE TransAm_School_Name__c != null
    AND TransAm_School_Visit_Status__c = 'Completed'
]) names.add(record.TransAm_School_Name__c);
List<Account> schools = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :names];
```

Comment: I need it to be SOQL

Comment: @gary69 Then the answer is it's impossible in one query. You would need to do some batches or data loading to massage the data to a point where you could do it with just one query.